# How to compile and run lower version java to higher version?

Tags: java

I am currently working in jdk 1.5 version. I want to compile and execute code in jdk 1.6 version.

How can i do this?

Comment: Every jdk version provides backword compatibility

Comment: BTW as Java 6 is end of the line, perhaps you should consider Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

If you're asking whether you can compile code with JDK 1.5 and run it with JDK 1.6, yes, that's fine. 1.6 can run code compiled with 1.5 without trouble. You won't be able to make use of any of the Java 6 (1.6) compile-time or API enhancements, of course. To do that, you'd have to compile with the 1.6 (or higher) JDK.

If you're asking how to start using 1.6, just install it and start using it. (That's a very general and somewhat vague answer, but then, it's a *very* general and vague question.)

Comment: The above statement is fine. I will come back

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-target` and `-source` flags to tell the compiler what source version you are using or  what target version you plan to run it on

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.5 [classes to compile etc]
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options

Answer (score 1):

Install `JDK 1.6` and re-set your `JAVA_HOME` variable. Normally, the code from the older platform versions will work on newer ones.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that? I'm using IntelliJ and when building a 1.5 project with Java 22 or 17, it keeps complaining either to "Downgrade Project SDK in settings to 1.5 or compatible" or to "Upgrade language version in Maven build file to XX". 2nd option throws further incompatibilities; 1st one I don't know how to do it, as it's not easy for me to find Java SDK 1.5 and I think it's not clever to have to do that when I'm supposed to be able to compile to bytecode for that version with my current SDK. but changing the project bytecode version or the "Language level" to 5 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an IDE, there must be an option with the location of java compiler, change to the directory of your installation of your new jdk.

else, change the value of your environement variable JAVA_HOME to the directory of your installation of your new jdk.

you don't have any change to do in your code

Answer (score 1):

jdk 1.6 supports all features present in jdk 1.5.So u can compile and run your program on jdk1.6 without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java is backwards compatible, so you can compile and run your application on 1.6 without any problems but maybe with some warning messages on compile.

You can use also the arguments -target and -source. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the java documentation about compatibility issues.
[Find here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html)